# Which version of Adobe Acrobat do I need to do calculations?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, interaction

We are trying to create a fillable PDF with Adobe Reader, I think, and seems to be working but we can't create calculations in it. Do we need a special version of Acrobat for this?

Answer (score 3):

Acrobat Pro has had forms with calculations a long time. It's not freeware, but quite a premium piece of software.

Search for "PDF form calculations" or "PDF forms with calculations", You get plenty of quidance to choose from. An example: https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/print/how-to-do-not-so-simple-form-calculations

The same search gives also several hints how to use freeware.

Foxit Phantom presents itself as a low cost alternative for Acrobat. It also has forms with calculations. I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Standard or Pro would do it.

When it comes to smart form, I'd be very reluctant to use another application to create, because their JavaScript support may be incomplete or "different".